# instantiating a php subprocess in background

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on an application based on running process in Server background "scraping and inserting in db", and checking the scraped data every X seconds by AJAX requests.

scrapping is running well in background by Nodejs service, the problem with insertion in database by PHP.

my first approach was to create AJAX request but because of PHPSESSID the server put any upcoming requests in queue causes to hang the response until the previous -long time taking request- finish.

my second approach was running curl in background using exec

`exec("curl 'someUrl' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");`

it returned to the state of queue requests.

Comment: There is not enough information here to give a good answer. So the server is nodejs but it uses PHP for updates? Or are the updates coming from somewhere else? Which part is using sessions? Is the problem a blocked database or something else?

Comment: node js has nothing todo with the problem i was just explaining the whole process. node is responsible for scraping and writing in json files which php read from and them write to db.
sessions is only concerned to php part.
the problem is to run php subprocess or another without going to the queue problem caused by server.